# Why my Python timestamp to datetime conversion is wrong?

Tags: python-2.7, timestamp, epoch

Portal *epochconverter.com* converts timestamp **1531423084013** to correct date of **Thursday, July 12, 2018 3:18:04.013 PM GMT-04:00 DST**. But in Python 2.7.12 I got below which is wrong

```
>>> timestamp=1531423084013

>>> time.ctime(timestamp).rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
'Wed Nov 12 00:06:53'
```

How to make it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1531423084013` is in milliseconds not is seconds.
As you can see from epochconverter.com the hour is : `3:18:04.013`, so the seconds part is `4.013`, this site handle time in seconds and in milliseconds (it seems when the input has 13 digits instead of 10 for time around nowadays).
But time.ctime() from python handle only time in seconds and this is why you get a wrong answer when you enter a time in milliseconds (in my system it throws an out of range).

So you must divide your time in milliseconds by 1000 :

```
time.ctime(1531423084)
'Thu Jul 12 21:18:04 2018'
```

(My time zone is UTC+0200)